# Oracle JDeveloper 12C doesn't show anything except the folder structures in Database Explorer

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I've added a db connection to 12C Database. I can query the tables successfully but I can't see any tables or any content in the Database Explorer except for the folder structure.

Comment: Does the user you are connected as own any objects - or are you querying another user's objects (either explicitly with a schema prefix, or via a (public) synonym, or after setting `current_schema`)?

Comment: @AlexPoole a simple select * from table_name but table_name can't be seen under tables folder. Tables folder supposedly have dozens of tables and I can query them just fine. I just can't see them in Database Explorer